# If $d\mid n$, element of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ of highest order is also element of $(\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z})^*$ of highest order

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am not entirely sure if the following lemma is true, but after running a code to check, for smaller values of $n$, it holds. Can someone outline the proof or give a counterexample for it. Lemma:

Let $g$ be the element of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ (multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$) of the highest order, that is, with order equal to $\lambda(n)$ where $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function. If $d | n$, then $g$ is the element of $(\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z})^*$ of the highest order.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. If $g$ is a generator for the (cyclic) group, then the order of that element will be the order of the group.

Comment: @Thomas I think 'generator' should just be read as 'element.' (Generally the group will not be cyclic.) More completely the $g$ is an element of maximum order of the group.

Comment: @quid: If that is true, then that would make more sense. Aalok, I would edit your question and replace the word "generator" by "element". Otherwise people (like me) could be confused.

Comment: As $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is not necessarily cyclic, the order of generator with the highest order need not be the size of the group. Consider  $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^*$ = $\{1,3,5,7\}$. Here, $3$, $5$ and $7$ have order 2, but the order of the group is 4. 

I hope it explains the concern.

Comment: @AalokThakkar: And so I wouldn't call $3$ a generator of the group.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. For instance  $\lambda(15)= 4$ and the multiplicative order of $7$  modulo $15$ is $4$, yet the multiplicative order of $7$ modulo $3$ is $1$ and not $\lambda(3) = 2$.

Comment: Can we prove that there exists one such element $g$ with highest order in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ such that it also has the highest order in $(\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z})^*$? 

I ran a code to check it and it turns out that the property holds for first thousand natural numbers.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I will try to include the details later (a day).